# @refreshScope Spring cloud config doesn't refresh application.properties value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I tried to use the annotation  @RefreshScope on my rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class SpringCloudControllerTest {

@Value("${data}")
private String value;

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> testPropertiesFile(){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(value);
}
```

the @Value annotation refers the application.properties on my remote repository:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
data=2
```

if i change my file in this way:

```
 management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
 data=3
```

and run the request on my client side http://localhost:8081/actuator/refresh
the response is just:

```
 [
 "config.client.version"
 ]
```

I don't see any response about my changes and if i run the request

```
 localhost:8081
```

the response is always "2"

these are my dependency on client side:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-config', version: '2.2.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version:'2.3.7.RELEASE'
```

thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

I change my application name file (client side) from application.yml to bootstrap.yml

Now when i run localhost:8081/actuator/refresh i have got this response

```
[
"config.client.version",
"data",
"spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled"
]
```

thank you all